# Accessing position information in a scala combinatorparser kills performance

Tags: performance, parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I wrote a new combinator for my parser in scala.

Its a variation of the ^^ combinator, which passes position information on.
But accessing the position information of the input element really cost performance.

In my case parsing a big example need around 3 seconds without position information, with it needs over 30 seconds.

I wrote a runnable example where the runtime is about 50% more when accessing the position.

Why is that? How can I get a better runtime?

Example:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.language.implicitConversions
object FooParser extends RegexParsers with Parsers {
  var withPosInfo = false
  def b: Parser[String] = regexB("""[a-z]+""".r)  ^^@ { case (b, x) => b + " ::" + x.toString }
  def regexB(p: Regex): BParser[String] = new BParser(regex(p))
  class BParser[T](p: Parser[T]) {
    def ^^@[U](f: ((Int, Int), T) => U): Parser[U] = Parser { in =>
      val source = in.source
      val offset = in.offset
      val start = handleWhiteSpace(source, offset)
      val inwo = in.drop(start - offset)
      p(inwo) match {
        case Success(t, in1) =>
          {
            var a = 3
            var b = 4
            if(withPosInfo)
            { // takes a lot of time
              a = inwo.pos.line
              b = inwo.pos.column
            }            
            Success(f((a, b), t), in1)
          }
        case ns: NoSuccess => ns
      }
    }
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val r = "foo"*50000000
    var now = System.nanoTime

    parseAll(b, r) 
    var us = (System.nanoTime - now) / 1000
    println("without: %d us".format(us))
    withPosInfo = true
    now = System.nanoTime
    parseAll(b, r)
    us = (System.nanoTime - now) / 1000
    println("with   : %d us".format(us))
  }
}
```

Output:

> without: 2952496 us
>
> with   : 4591070 us

Comment: Thanks, I changed it. In this small example its only 50% more, but the factor increased with the number of accesses, which in my real code is roughly equal to the number of elements in my abstract syntax tree. So it depends :)

Comment: (Deleted the other comment as it's now irrelevant.  Except you should probably change your variable name from `ms` to `us` also.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can use the same approach.  The problem is that line numbers end up implemented by `scala.util.parsing.input.OffsetPosition` which builds a list of *every line break every time it is created*.  So if it ends up with string input it will parse the entire thing on every call to `pos` (twice in your example).  See the code for [CharSequenceReader](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/util/parsing/input/CharSequenceReader.scala#L1) and [OffsetPosition](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/util/parsing/input/OffsetPosition.scala#L1) for more details.

There is one quick thing you can do to speed this up:

```
val ip = inwo.pos
a = ip.line
b = ip.column
```

to at least avoid creating `pos` twice.  But that still leaves you with a lot of redundant work.  I'm afraid to really solve the problem you'll have to build the index as in `OffsetPosition` yourself, just once, and then keep referring to it.

You could also file a bug report / make an enhancement request.  This is not a very good way to implement the feature.

Comment: For those that come across this answer OffsetPosition has been modified to fix this issue -- https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/commit/b8b0f8758bd8425e5a0bcd5cc920f0e21a46c480

Comment: But note that this is after 1.0.4 (current latest version).